# How to Run Program from bash and run scripts inside that program?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

My Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd dataset/
root
.x Pushkar_Soni.cpp
```

What I am trying to do is:

1) launch root by command `root`

2) Inside the launched program root I want to run scripts `.x Pushkar_Soni.cpp`

But what happening is my last command `.x Pushkar_Soni.cpp` is executed after I quit root by the command `.q`, I want my last command to run Inside the program root

```
Pushkars-MacBook-Air:Pushkar_Soni pushkarsoni$ bash ./build.sh
 ------------------------------------------------------------
| Welcome to ROOT 6.17/01                  https://root.cern |
|                               (c) 1995-2019, The ROOT Team |
| Built for macosx64 on Mar 18 2019, 16:04:57                |
| From heads/master@v6-16-00-rc1-1322-gf3f829884a            |
| Try '.help', '.demo', '.license', '.credits', '.quit'/'.q' |
 ------------------------------------------------------------

root [0] .q
./build.sh: line 4: .x: command not found
Pushkars-MacBook-Air:Pushkar_Soni pushkarsoni$
```

Comment: From what I can tell from `root`s [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/root), its signature is "**root** _[options] files_", meaning you should be able to just say `root Pushkar_Soni.cpp` instead of the last two lines in your script.

Comment: @Entropy0 You Solved my Exact Problem. Tq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from roots [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/root), its signature is

**root** *[options] files*

, meaning you should be able to just say

```
root Pushkar_Soni.cpp
```

instead of the last two lines in your script.